# Nested routes on shared component loaded dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would define sub routes config in constructor of child component shared between multiple routes but it throws conflict exception.

App routes config :

```
...
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/child-a/...',
    name: 'ChildA',
    data: {foo: 'A'},
    component: ChildComponent,  // <== Same component on route "A" and "B"
    useAsDefault: true
  },
  {
    path: '/child-b/...',
    name: 'ChildB',
    data: {foo: 'B'},
    component: ChildComponent,  // <== Same component on route "A" and "B"
  }
])
export class App {}
```

Nested routes in ChildComponent:

```
...

  constructor(
    private routeData: RouteData,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.foo = this.routeData.get('foo');

    this.router.config([
      {
        path: '/nested-z',
        name: 'NestedZ',
        component: NestedChildComponent,
        data: {parentFoo: this.foo}
      }
    ]);

    // router.config should trigger "renavigate"

  }
...
```

But when I navigate from "Route A" to "Route B", it thows this exception :

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Configuration '/nested-z' conflicts with existing
>   route '/nested-z'

Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/xYsxtQE69GaM2kyohgNZ?p=preview

How could i define nested routes on a component shared between multiple parent routes ?

Comment: Have you tried returning `false` from `routerCanReuse()`? I don't know what the default behavior is when `CanReuse` is not implemented.